# A word for someone who loves searching, learning new things?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a suitable word or expression, for someone who really loves to learn, search and read about new things (Technologies, science, economics, politics..), so that his passion is only to acquire more knowledge.

Comment: A related word is *autodidact*: "self-taught person: somebody whose knowledge is self-taught".

Comment: @MrHen: Ha! Jinx!

Comment: Oh, that's awesome. I would never have found *philomath*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You [might call such a person](http://www.alphadictionary.com/articles/philias.html) a:

> ***Epistemophile***: one who has a love of knowledge; specifically, excessive striving for or preoccupation with knowledge.
>
> ***Philosophile***: Similar, but more of an emphasis on *learning and philosophy*.
>
> ***Sophophile***: Similar, but with more of an emphasis on *gaining wisdom*.

A little further afield, some define the doctrine of [*gnosticism*](http://phrontistery.info/isms.html), and its members, the ***Gnostics***, as subscribing to the:

> belief that freedom derives solely from knowledge

Note that *Gnosticism* is variously defined, and this description is not even the most popular or common. However, as @JasperLocke points out, the more generic

> ***Gnosiophile***

Isn't connected to the Gnostic sect, and so doesn't have the religious/spiritural/mystical connotations.

**Bonus**, for the true *epistemophile*: one who is ***self-taught*** is called a ***[autodidact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_notable_autodidacts)***.

<sub>Sources: Alpha Dictionary; Phronistery.info; Wikipedia</sub>

Comment: I think you should add gnosiophilia, which is love of knowledge as well. On a side note, I'd consider myself an autodidact.

Comment: Thanks @JasperLocke, added (and you're in good company!)

Answer (score 2):

Nouns that come close: *seeker*, *searcher*, *learner*, but they could benefit from an adjective: *knowledge (or truth) seeker* (or *searcher*), *avid learner*.

Adjectives that come close: *curious*, *inquisitive*.

Answer (score 1):

In business theory, the term "early adopter" is used to describe this type of person.

"In the diffusion of innovation theory, the minority group (comprising about 14 percent) of population which, after innovators, is first to try new ideas, processes, goods and services. Early adopters generally rely on their on intuition and vision, choose carefully, and have above-average education level. For any new product to be successful, it must attract innovators and early adopters, so that its acceptance or 'diffusion' moves on to early majority, late majority, and then on to laggards."
http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/early-adopters.html

In politics, fashion, art, and other fields, this person would be referred to as a "trendsetter".

A much older word that applies is a "philomath", a lover of learning. (from Greek "phil" meaning "loving" and "math" meaning "to learn")

Answer (score 0):

There's *philomath*:

> (archaic) A lover of learning; a scholar.

from http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/philomath and http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Philomath.