# Lover of Science

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word that describes a lover of general science?
A philomath is a lover of learning and a philonoist is one who seeks knowledge.  I am looking for a word that ends in 'phile

Comment: A **science** [**enthusiast**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enthusiast)?

Comment: Are you looking for single word or a phrase? Have you checked a list of [-philes](http://www.alphadictionary.com/articles/philias.html)?

Comment: The traditional answer is a *philosopher*, which comes from [philosophy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=philosophy) (philo = love, sophia = wisdom). [Support for the link between philosophy and science.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/natural-philosophy)The modern understanding has specialised this to an academic context, hence the Ph in Ph.D. I know you wanted the word to end in 'phile, but if you don't mind that (a version of) it is at the *front* end :) and that the meaning of the word is specialised, I'll post it as an answer. Let me know.

Comment: I back Lawrence's answer and further add that at the time of the Enlightenment, the first perhaps 'true' or empirical scientists referred to themselves as Natural Philosophers.

Comment: You might find something useful in this old answer of mine: *[A word for someone who loves searching, learning new things?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190352/a-word-for-someone-who-loves-searching-learning-new-things/190354#190354)* or in the older question it was closed as a duplicate of: *[What term means “one who enjoys learning”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163232/what-term-means-one-who-enjoys-learning)*.

Comment: Thanks but none of the above cuts the mustard.  In 'Trivial Pursuit' there is a cheese for 'Science and Nature'.  General Science, when I took the subject at 'O' level, was literally that and covered Chemistry, Physics, and Biology all of which were independent and detailed subjects.

Comment: Gnosophile? (Someone who loves knowledge -> greek gnosis, latin scientia)

Comment: The word you are looking could be Technophile - one who loves technology. I also was thinking of Didactophile- one who loves learning, but I have only come across this word once in a science fiction book and have not seen it in a dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to boast about science you could compare the enthusiast to a philocaly (lover of beauty). Not all of these nouns end in 'phil' but they do contain it. Philomath can also be defined specifically as a lover of maths and sciences. You could also try looking for a word that contains the suffix '-mania'.

- zoophilia/philotherianism - zoologist
- thalassophilous - oceanographer
- phytophilous/dendrophilous - botany
- anthomania/florimania - botany
- arithmomania - mathematician
- zoomania - zoologist

Comment: Please don't use the word "zoophilia" if you want to indicate "a lover of zoology." The word is actually used to refer to sexual attraction to animals.

Comment: All the words you listed ending in "-ous" are adjectives, not nouns, and some of them don't have appropriate meanings either. "Phytophilous" is an adjective that's generally used as a synonym for "herbivorous."